# images added to to web-app/images folder getting 404 in GRAILS app

Tags: image, grails, http-status-code-404, grails-2.0

this is driving me nuts.

so i have a grails 2.0 app that i'm working on. today i added a new png into web-app/images directory, but for some reason when i go to it in the browser it doesn't show up. for example when i pasted this in my browser

```
http://localhost:8080/static/images/logo.png
```

the logo got served. i even cleared my cache to make sure i wasn't being served a cached version

then then i did

```
http://localhost:8080/static/images/test.png
```

and i get a 404.

then i tried curling both urls in the terminal and same results. logo.png returns the image data, while test.png returns the 404 html.

both images are in the same directory. i even did an ls -la to check the permissions, and they're both the same.

the odd thing was that it was being served earlier today. can't figure out what changed. i even reverted my code base to earlier versions and i'm getting the same error.

any suggestions would be appreciated! this is driving me nuts. so close to finishing the feature i'm working on =(

Comment: have you tried 'grails clean' and then run? are you running in dev mode or deployed as a war?

Comment: yeah i tried that too. cleaned, even deleted all contents in the target directory. also tried run-war, and packing to a war and putting it in tomcat, but same result.

Comment: i changed the logging level in grails and did get this WARN message when starting grails though: **servlet.DefaultGrailsApplicationAttributes  - ApplicationContext not found in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.APPLICATION_CONTEXT attribute of servlet context.** it came after configuring spring security. not sure if that has anything to do with this.

Comment: some really weird things are happening. so deleted the logo.png and as expected it gets a 404. i put it back and it gets served. i then make a copy rename it to test2.png put it into the web-app images and i get a 404.. i then renamed logo.png to logo2.png and logo2.png gets a 404. i renamed test2.png to logo.png and i STILL get a 404..  don't know what to make of this. i restarted grails between each trail and did a clean as well.

Comment: i think i'm getting closer.. after more googling, i found that if i do http://localhost:8080/images/test.png?_debugResources=y. that's supposed to bypass some processing..now just gotta figure out the cause of this issue.

Comment: so i found a work around.. not a fix. still not sure what the cause is. in the js file, i'm building the img tag "<img src='/static/images/test.png'/>" which gives me the 404 error in the console. but if i do "var img = "${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'qrcode/qrcode.png')}";" in the gsp page. it works. i'm assuming it somehow registers it with the resource plugin in grails. anyone with any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? The output into my view stopped working after the second time I used it.

Comment: @John Giotta i wouldn't say it's resolved, but i did do a work around. check out my comment to bouquetf's answer. i think it has something to do with the resource plugin not registering the asset unless it's accessed via one of it's tag libs. but yeah, output to your view stopped working? that sounds a little different from my issue. mine was just an image asset not being accessible via a direct url. maybe there was an exception that stopped your view from rendering. if your issue is different, maybe post a new question? that way we have more details to try to help out.

Comment: this might be kind of late to respond but spring security is probably causing that issue. spring security's filters intercept all incoming requests and apply filters to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the resource using the createLinkTo gsp tag.

It may also be a cache issue. Have you tryed redeploying your web application ?

Cheers

Comment: yeah, i actually did something similar. i did "var img = "${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'qrcode/qrcode.png')}";" on the gsp page. somehow doing that worked. i assume when i use the grails tag lib it registers the image with the resource plugin. and yeah i did re-deploy and clear all my cache. hopefully this is just a bug on grails 2.0.1. i know they're up to 2.0.4 as of this writing. just haven't had time to upgrade. thanks bouquetf.

Answer (score 0):

^_^ now I can fix this issue for me. hope this can help.

I change resources plugin from 1.1.6 (that integrated in Grails 2.2.1) to lastest version (1.2.RC2) and it work.